# How to send a Marketplace URL for an app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

How to send URL within app to download this app? Example:

> "Hello. I like this app which you can install at *URL in marketplace*."

Comment: Send to whom and send how?? Elaborate your question a bit

Comment: Send by sms/email link with app thats running, like "recommend this app to a friend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generating-a-Windows-Phone-9d19f939/) on how to create an install link from within your app.

After getting the link, just use one of the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) classes to send a mail or sms or anything else you require!

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question is old, but for anyone who found this through a search, this is the format for URLs to apps:

http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=yourappid

This link will open your app on the WP website if clicked from a computer, or show your app in the store app if clicked from a WP device.

Your app ID is in the format xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx and can be found in the Dev Center details page or at the end of the URL of the app page on the Windows Phone website.

Then use the `SMSComposeTask` or `EmailComposeTask` classes to send the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MarketplaceDetailTask to which you need to provide the app id using which it will display the App page of that app in the marketplace. You can learn about it and other tasks related to marketplace here at: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/6-how-to-use-marketplace-tasks-in-a-wp7-app. Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to display my app by clicking url in sms/email from other device where sms was sended.